# Top 5 Rankings Issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I'm wondering if this is even the best way to manage my data for this table because with my query I'm not getting the correct results I want.

I am wanting it to grab the top5 rankings from the last date entry in the table. A problem is if there is a 0 for the character_id. When I do my php to see if there isn't a value then it should echo TBD but its still not showing it in the array to be 0.

Table: top5

```
id    ranking #    character_id    status_id    date_created
1         1           1                1         2011-10-17 17:18:54 
2         2           2                1         2011-10-17 17:18:54    
3         3           3                1         2011-10-17 17:18:54
4         4           4                1         2011-10-17 17:18:54
5         5           5                1         2011-10-17 17:18:54
6         1           6                1         2011-10-24 12:18:54
7         2           7                1         2011-10-24 12:18:54
8         3           8                1         2011-10-24 12:18:54
9         4           9                1         2011-10-24 12:18:54
10        5           0                1         2011-10-24 12:18:54

function getTop5()
{
    $this->db->select('characters.character_name, top5.character_id'); 
    $this->db->from('top5'); 
    $this->db->join('characters', 'characters.id = top5.character_id'); 
    $this->db->where('top5.status_id', '1');  
    $this->db->order_by('top5.date_created','desc');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

Array ( [0] => 
       Array ( [character_name] => \"Mr. Magnificent\" Matt Sharp 
               [character_id] => 9 ) 
        [1] => 
       Array ( [character_name] => \"The Unforgettable\" Jimmy Watkins 
               [character_id] => 8 ) 
        [2] => 
       Array ( [character_name] => Romie Rains 
               [character_id] => 7 ) 
        [3] => 
       Array ( [character_name] => Monica Dawson 
               [character_id] => 6 ) 
        [4] => 
       Array ( [character_name] => \"The Outlaw\" Mike Mayhem 
               [character_id] => 5 ) )
```

EDIT: Anyone else want to give it a try?

So lost and can't get the desired results still

Comment: I guess you want `order_by('top5.ranking');
`

Comment: I assume that last day is 24th ?

Comment: "last day" means current day or yesterday? Or last recorded date in table?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what db class is it, but just append

```
AND date(date_created) = CURDATE();
```

to the query

or append `DESC` to `ORDER` clause

So something like

```
$this->db->select('characters.character_name, top5.character_id'); 
$this->db->from('top5'); 
$this->db->join('characters', 'characters.id = top5.character_id'); 
$this->db->where('top5.status_id', '1'); 
// WHERE date(top5.date_created) = CURDATE() 
$this->db->order_by('top5.date_created');
$this->db->limit(5);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: `NOW()` includes the time also, so it wouldn't work to get everything on the same day. You'd want to do `AND DATE(date_created) = CURDATE()`

Comment: I've updated my post with what the returned array looks like which is not the right information.

Comment: @BrianGlaz: ah, thanks. I have never worked with date column, so I wasn't aware of that

Comment: That wouldn't work Brian because these are going to be for each month so the same results should be for the same time 3 weeks from now.

Comment: So I need to add in the commented line?

Comment: @Mr.Magoo: no. I said I do not know how your db class works, so you should edit it

Comment: Then I see no change from mine.

Comment: using DATE() and CURDATE(), the time is irrelevant. I also noticed that your question mentions getting results from the PREVIOUS day, so you want to do `AND DATE(date_created) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: @Mr.Magoo: I said you have to modificate it to add that comented line into your query

Comment: Its not from the previous day. When I said I meant last day I meant from the last date entry in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to order by `top5.date_created` in descending order. If you really only want the last day, you'd also want a WHERE condition for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getTop5()
{
    $this->db->select('characters.character_name, top5.character_id'); 
    $this->db->from('top5'); 
    $this->db->join('characters', 'characters.id = top5.character_id'); 
    $this->db->join( '( SELECT DATE(MAX(date_created)) AS lastdate
                        FROM top5 
                        WHERE status_id = 1
                      ) AS tm'
                   , 'top5.created_at >= tm.lastdate 
                      AND top5.created_at < tm.lastdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY'); 
    $this->db->where('top5.status_id', '1'); 
    $this->db->order_by('top5.ranking','asc');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Its not from the last day its from the last date entry. There's a difference.

Comment: @Mr.Magoo: I can't understand what your last comment is about. Last day, last date, what is the difference?

Comment: Its the last date entry. So from the table itd be the bottom 5 entries, because their date is more recent.

Comment: I was thinking I was going to need it for this query. This is all written for CodeIgniter.

Comment: Your query should be working correctly and show the last 5 entries (with status_id=1). Unless your methods (like the `limit()` one) do not work properly.

Comment: I have to limit 5 because otherwise it would show ALL the entries